# AVAssetWriter queue guidance Swift 3

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

Can anyone give me some guidance on using queues in AVFoundation, please?

Later on, in my app, I want to do some processing on individual frames so I need to use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.

To get started I thought I'd capture images and then write them (unprocessed) using `AVAssetWriter`.

I am successfully streaming frames from the camera to image preview by setting up an `AVCaptureSession` as follows:

```
func initializeCameraAndMicrophone() {
    
    // set up the captureSession
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 // set resolution to Medium

    // set up the camera
    let camera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    
    do {
        let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
        if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput){
            captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error setting device camera input: \(error)")
        return
    }

    videoOutputStream.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "sampleBuffer", attributes: []))
    
    if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutputStream) {
        captureSession.addOutput(videoOutputStream)
    }
    
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
```

Each new frame then triggers the `captureOutput` delegate:

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
{
    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
    let bufferImage = UIImage(ciImage: cameraImage)

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // send captured frame to the videoPreview
        self.videoPreview.image = bufferImage
        
        // if recording is active append bufferImage to video frame
        while (recordingNow == true) {
            print("OK we're recording!")
                      
            // append images to video 
            while (writerInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {
                let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(frameCount), videoFPS)
                let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)

                pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)
               
                frameCount += 1              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this streams frames to the image preview perfectly until I press the record button which calls the `startVideoRecording` function (which sets up `AVAssetWriter`). From that point on the delegate never gets called again!

`AVAssetWriter` is being set up like this:

```
func startVideoRecording() {
    guard let assetWriter = createAssetWriter(path: filePath!, size: videoSize) else {
        print("Error converting images to video: AVAssetWriter not created")
        return
    }

    // AVAssetWriter exists so create AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor
    let writerInput = assetWriter.inputs.filter{ $0.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo }.first!
    
    let sourceBufferAttributes: [String : AnyObject] = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB) as AnyObject,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String : videoSize.width as AnyObject,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String : videoSize.height as AnyObject,
    ]
    
    let pixelBufferAdaptor = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor(assetWriterInput: writerInput, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: sourceBufferAttributes)
    
    // Start writing session
    assetWriter.startWriting()
    assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: kCMTimeZero)
    if (pixelBufferAdaptor.pixelBufferPool == nil) {
        print("Error converting images to video: pixelBufferPool nil after starting session")
        
        assetWriter.finishWriting{
            print("assetWritter stopped!")
        }
        recordingNow = false
        
        return
    }
    
    frameCount = 0
    
    print("Recording started!")
}
```

I'm new to AVFoundation but I suspect I'm screwing up my queues somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a separate serial queue for capturing video/audio.

1. Add this queue property to your class:

   ```
   let captureSessionQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sampleBuffer", attributes: [])
   ```
2. Start the session on captureSessionQueue, according to the Apple docs:
        The startRunning() method is a blocking call which can take some time, therefore you should
        perform session setup on a serial queue so that the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive).

   ```
   captureSessionQueue.async {
       captureSession.startRunning()
   }
   ```
3. Set this queue to your capture output pixel buffer delegate:

   ```
   videoOutputStream.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureSessionQueue)
   ```
4. Call startVideoRecording inside captureSessionQueue:

   ```
   captureSessionQueue.async {
       startVideoRecording()
   }
   ```
5. In the captureOutput delegate method put all AVFoundation methods calls into captureSessionQueue.async:

   ```
   DispatchQueue.main.async
     {

       // send captured frame to the videoPreview
       self.videoPreview.image = bufferImage

       captureSessionQueue.async {
           // if recording is active append bufferImage to video frame
           while (recordingNow == true){

               print("OK we're recording!")

               /// Append images to video 
               while (writerInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData) {

                   let lastFrameTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(frameCount), videoFPS)
                   let presentationTime = frameCount == 0 ? lastFrameTime : CMTimeAdd(lastFrameTime, frameDuration)

                   pixelBufferAdaptor.append(pixelBuffer!, withPresentationTime: presentationTime)


                   frameCount += 1              
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Could you advise how one would go about calling `finishWriting()` using the above?  I've used your code to accomplish a better experience writing to AVAssetWriter, but despite calling `finishWriting()` on either the captureSessionQueue or Main Queue, I end up with a blank video.

Comment: @ninjaproger Can You elaborate a bit more about `You have to use a separate serial queue for capturing video/audio.`?
If I have a `videoQueue` and a `audioQueue` on which one should I start the `startRunning()` method? Or should I have a third Queue for that?